# No Factories configured for this Application

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, myfaces

I am trying to run a JSF 2.0 webapp using Apache MyFaces 2.1.8 on a Tomcat 7 webserver.When i try to load a simple page i get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This           happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include     all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
>
> If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
>   A typical config looks like this;
>
> ```
> <listener>
>   <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> ```

what should I do to fix it? Thanx!

Edit:

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why don't you just **read** the error message? The answer is in there!

Comment: actually my configuration  is good i ve oncluded all the necessary libs

Comment: Sorry, but the exception indicates otherwise :) Re-read it.

Comment: i've followed a tutoriel and i ve included all the libs necessary maybe it's a porblem of libs but i cant figure it out

Comment: Did you add the <listener-class> entry as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same error message, using what I knew to be a good JSF portlet project set up (i.e. the values in the web.xml, faces-config.xml and in my case portlet.xml were all accurate).

It turns out my problem was being caused by the inclusion of the Apache commons jar files; I've not identified which one in particular caused the issue yet, but after removing the following jars as dependencies from the project the error's stopped appearing:

- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar
- commons-lang-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Looking at this list it appears the "commons-codec-1.3.jar" and "commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" jars are common between my setup and yours, so maybe start by removing one or both of these and see what difference that makes?

Edit: I've hit the problem again in another project which had commons-logging-1.1.1.jar present in the web application, and removing this has stopped the error from appearing.